# My program needs a other program

Tags: python, quickly, pygtk, debian-installer

For my program i need android-tools-adb. How can i include this in my debian package?

Or is there an other way to handle this problem? I remember that Rhythmbox asked you an question if you want to install the MP3 codex on first installation on ubuntu. How Can i handle this question in pygtk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your control file in debian/DEBIAN folder, edit "Depends" field.

Example of control file:

```
Package: root-your-phone-tool
Version: 1.0.0
Architecture: all
Section: base
Maintainer: Gustaf Haglund <john.doe@example.com>
Depends: android-tools-adb, python, python-gtk2
Description: Root your phone easily with this tool.
```